# Why doesn't "<a></a>" become the parent element when appending it via jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm creating elements with jQuery and then appending them to existing HTML. Here is my jQuery code:

```
var h1 = $(data2).find("h1").html();
var image = $(data2).find(".tutorialContent .wsite-image:first-child").html();
$(".searchResults").append('<a class="searchResultsImageTitle">' + '<div class="searchResultsImage">' + image + '</div>' + '<div class="searchResultsTitle">' + h1 + '</div>' + '</a>');});
```

I want the code above to produce this HTML:

```
<a class="searchResultsImageTitle">
  <div class="searchResultsImage"></div>
  <div class="searchResultsTitle"></div>
</a>
```

But instead I get this HTML:

```
<a class="searchResultsImageTitle"></a>
<div class="searchResultsImage"></div>
<div class="searchResultsTitle"></div>
```

Comment: did you try to have `<span>` tags instead of `<div>`, your code will output invalid HTML, maybe replacing the `<div>` with `<span>` would work for you. checkout this [is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: When removing the }); at the end of your append(), it works: https://jsfiddle.net/32nbp08k/

Answer (score 0):

Your code have error syntax, refined it, the code the a tag still wrap 2 div inside as

```
<a class="searchResultsImageTitle">
  <div class="searchResultsImage"></div>
  <div class="searchResultsTitle"></div>
</a>
```

```js
$(".searchResults").append('<a class="searchResultsImageTitle" href="#">' + '<div class="searchResultsImage">' + 'image' + '</div>' + '<div class="searchResultsTitle">' + 'h1' + '</div>' + '</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchResults"></div>
```

Comment: With the addition of the apostrophes around the variables, the variables are now invalid. Sorry, I should have included the variables from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I broke it up just a bit but this should do the trick

```js
const $a = $('<a class="searchResultsImageTitle">');
const $d1 = $('<div class="searchResultsImage">');
const $d2 = $('<div class="searchResultsTitle">');

$a.append($d1);
$a.append($d2);
$(".searchResults").append($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

When removing the }); at the end of your `append()`, it works:

```js
let image = "<img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff'/>";
let h1 = "<h1>Title</h1>";
$(".searchResults").append('<a class="searchResultsImageTitle">' + '<div class="searchResultsImage">' + image + '</div>' + '<div class="searchResultsTitle">' + h1 + '</div>' + '</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchResults">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone's answers! I discovered the problem to be a conflict between the jQuery code and the HTML one of the variables was pulling. Thank you all!